# Openslides on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, openslide

I'm trying to install [Openslide](https://openslide.org/api/python/) to visualize medical pictures.
I have followed the simple instructions but I couldn't successfully start Openslide on my laptop.

I used:

```
pip install openslides
```

but i get this error when i run "openslides" from my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/andrea/.local/bin/openslides", line 7, in <module>
from openslides.__main__ import main
File "/home/andrea/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openslides/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
from openslides.utils.arguments import arguments
File "/home/andrea/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openslides/utils/arguments.py", line 8
def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Any:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried using the [openslides-python](https://github.com/openslide/openslide-python) package but i cannot figure out how to evoke it from terminal.

I'm using Python 2.7

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: could you check if it works in python 3?

Comment: are you trying openslide api or intents to use from terminal ?

Comment: I'm currently using Python 2.7, I will add it to the question.
The library says this: 
    Python 2 >= 2.6 or Python 3 >= 3.3
    OpenSlide >= 3.4.0
    Python Imaging Library or Pillow

Comment: yep I read, but i'm not sure it's true.

Comment: because reading this one: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html makes me dubious it could work with python <3.5 too